# Erro: testemunho inválido ou trocado no PHPMYADMIN

Tags: phpmyadmin

Nunca vi esse erro antes, na internet nao tem praticamente nenhuma informação sobre isso

> Erro: testemunho inválido ou trocado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em qual opção isso acontece? o que vc estava tenta fazer?

Comment: selecionar banco , importar, qualquer ação que passe da tela inicial, da esse erro

Meu servidor está na hostgator

Comment: Significa que você não foi aprovado no círculo das testumanhas de Jeová. Já tentou um `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Limpa os [cookies e sessões](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en) ou se tiveres acesso ao `php.ini` remove os `;` da linha `session.save_path = "/tmp"` deve ser suficiente.